# Test framework quit unexpectetly; agent library failed to init: instrument

Tags: maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

Every time I'm starting a debug in IntelliJ I receive:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.4.3/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.4.3.jar

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I already

- Restarted, invalidated caches
- Updates all dependencies in the POM
- Re-downloaded the project
- Reset the project to various old branches
- Deleted local maven cache

It only occurs when I want to debug. Test, compile, run, all works - just debug doesn't. Debug works as usual on all other projects.

Has anyone an idea what the hell is going on?

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Does this suggestion help: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-17927#focus=Comments-27-4350044.0-0 ?

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! I can finally debug again. First comment solved my issue: `Does it help to "File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Kotlin | Disable coroutine agent"?`

Comment: Please post it as an answer so I can give you the 'correct answer' batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue: *[KTIJ-17927](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-17927) Debugger: "Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute" when debugging main function in jvmMain in MPP with coroutines*

The workaround is to set File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Kotlin | **Disable coroutine agent** option. Or update to the latest IDE and Kotlin plugin version where it should be fixed.